# Bootstrap checkbox buttons not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the checkbox button functionality described on the bootstrap page [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) under the subsection "checkbox". I copy pasted the html(shown below) from that page into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3mu8/305/) and checkboxes suddenly appear inside the buttons. How can I get rid of them? I couldn't find any mention of this issue on the Bootstrap site or using Google.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox">Option 1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox">Option 2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I found that calling .hide() on the input checkbox elements hides the checkbox and the checkboxes then look just like buttons as in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Whatdo you expect when you use `btn btn-primary` ?

Comment: You're using the wrong bootstrap version.

Comment: I expect it to look like it does on the bootstrap site, a normal blue button with no white checkbox in the middle.

Comment: @CalumMcCall The current bootstrap site show documentation for bootstrap 3+, however the bootstrap file on your fiddle is bootstrap 2.0.4 (at least the CSS) so if you're also using bootstrap 2.0.4, it won't works, you either need to change your bootstrap version or to look at bootstrap v2 doc: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks very much! I got it working in js fiddle just now using the latest version of bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSFIDDLE you're are using Bootstrap v2.0.4 .. that Boostrap doc site uses the newer Bootstrap v3.1.1

Check which version you have loaded in your development environment

For Boostrap 2.x.x you would need to do

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons

Answer (score 1):

**try this code for check boxes:**

```
<div>
  <label class="col-md-4">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="col-md-4">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="col-md-4">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

It is done in http://jsfiddle.net/g3mu8/307/.

**and and button here:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">option1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">option2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">option3</button>
</div>
```

done here http://jsfiddle.net/g3mu8/308/